# Opening HDF5 file without modifying file timestamp

Tags: r, hdf5, rhdf5

I am currently writing a function in R to convert the output of an external program (in `HDF5`) on a Linux machine to a different file format. I would need to retain the timestamps due to the way my pipeline is structured (mainly for reproducibility purposes).

My function currently just wraps `rhdf5::H5Fopen()` (with extra data transformation)

```
function(path_to_file){
  data <- rhdf5::H5Fopen(path_to_file,
    # preserve original file structure
    native = TRUE
  )

  data <- as.data.frame(data[["slot1"]])

  return(data)
}
```

However, this causes the timestamp (when the file was last modified) to be modified every time I read the file through the function. Is there any way to retain the original timestamp when opening the file? Thanks

Comment: When are you writing the file? And what are you returning?  Are you saying you don't want to change the last modified date or that you are having trouble with preserving the created date?

Comment: The file is generated by [a separate software](https://snipar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I am not writing it at any point (not intentionally, at the very least), but it seems that the file timestamp on my system (e.g., seen from `ls`) changes if I run `rhdf5::H5Fopen()`. I want to be able to read the file into R without changing the date it was created/last modified on my system. My function return is exclusively subsetting that object and return part of it, I will modify the question with a better minimal example!

Comment: Sorry, I think what I mean is "when the file was last modified", so mtime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the file in read only mode, then the timestamp won't be modified e.g.

```r
library(rhdf5)

h5file <- '/tmp/h5ex_t_array.h5'
file.mtime( h5file )
#> [1] "2022-06-27 15:23:43 CEST"

fid <- rhdf5:::H5Fopen( h5file, flags = 'H5F_ACC_RDONLY' )
H5Fclose(fid)
file.mtime( h5file )
#> [1] "2022-06-27 15:23:43 CEST"

fid <- rhdf5:::H5Fopen( h5file )
H5Fclose(fid)
file.mtime( h5file )
#> [1] "2024-02-08 12:24:53 CET"
```

Remember that you should always pair an open operation with a close in HDF5, otherwise you'll end up with potential file lock issues and memory leaks.  In this case that would be `H5Fclose()`.

It might be easier to use `h5read()`, which uses read only by default and handles the closing of files automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hack by getting modified time before opening and resetting it at the end.

```
function(path_to_file){
  mtime <- file.info(path_to_file)$mtime
  on.exit({
    Sys.setFileTime(path_to_file, mtime)
  })

  data <- rhdf5::H5Fopen(path_to_file,
    # preserve original file structure
    native = TRUE
  )

  data <- as.data.frame(data[["slot1"]])

  return(data)
}
```